# Pubsub Authorization Issue

Tags: google-api, google-cloud-platform, google-authentication

I've generated a Google Cloud API key without restrictions. I'm passing that to the my `topic:publish` url as a query parameter, but I'm experiencing an authorization error.

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": 403,
        "message": "User not authorized to perform this action.",
        "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
    }
}
```

I'm unsure how to diagnose the permission issue, as there don't appear to be any restrictions on the key. The owner of the topic is my account, so shouldn't be an issue there.

Answer (score 4):

Google Pub/Sub does not support API Keys for authorization. Pub/Sub uses Access Tokens. This means using a Service Account or Google OAuth.

Comment: Aaaah, that makes sense. Thanks kindly!